# RcppArmadillo "Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)" under Windows Platform

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I have some functions written in Rcpp and RcppArmadillo like this

---

example.cpp:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace Rcpp;
// using namespace RcppArmadillo;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double inner1(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  int K = x.length() ;
  double ip = 0 ;
  for (int k = 0 ; k < K ; k++) {
    ip += x(k) * y(k) ;
  }
  return(ip) ;
}



// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat multiply2(mat A, mat B) {
  return A * B;
}
```

---

Then I use `Rcpp::sourceCpp('example.cpp')` and It works well under Ubuntu.

(I have run `library(Rcpp)` and `library(RcppArmadillo)` before )

However, When I move to Windows Platform, the RStudio Throw an error said:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('R:/example.cpp')
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/[Username]/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpG6H80X/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.12.19/sourcecpp_40b04b2c2bcf/sourceCpp_4.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I found the key problem is in the matrix multiplication. Since I try to delete the second function `multiply2`. Then the rest of the code can be complied successfully under Windows.

example2.cpp

---

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace Rcpp;
// using namespace RcppArmadillo;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double inner1(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  int K = x.length() ;
  double ip = 0 ;
  for (int k = 0 ; k < K ; k++) {
    ip += x(k) * y(k) ;
  }
  return(ip) ;
}
```

---

I have tried some other codes, found that this error occurs when matrix multiplication `*` was used in code.

So, Why matrix multiplication in RcppArmadillo fails under Windows Platform?

Answer (score 2):

After the struggled with the compiler for a long time, I found the key point is the `BLAS` library was not correctly set in my windows system environment path.

In short, the solution is :

1. Download precompiled binary packages of OpenBLS at [Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.19/) (DO NOT try to compile the newest version under windows, I've waste a lot time on it)
2. Exactor `OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32.zip` to some where like `C:\LIBS\OpenBLAS-v0.2.15-Win64-int32`
3. Add `C:\LIBS\OpenBLAS-v0.2.15-Win64-int32\bin` to your `PATH`
4. [Optional] Create a new environment variable called `BLAS_LIBS`, which value is `C:\LIBS\OpenBLAS-v0.2.15-Win64-int32\bin`
5. Restart RStudio, and the problem was solved.

I find this solution by install `RcppArmadillo` from source by `install.packages("RcppArmadillo", type = "source")`, this time the RStudio throw the same error during the compiling, so the install fails.

However, if I just use `install.packages("RcppArmadillo")`, the RStudio will install binary version of `RcppArmadillo`, so I didn't get any feedback about the absence of `BLAS`.

Comment: I think a simpler approach has long been described in the _R Installation and Administration_ manual that ships with R.